# Flutter for web, can't type into a TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

So I'm creating a flutter for web application. A little risky but I really just want an initial prototype, and hopefully by the time I need something production ready it's in at least beta.

Anyways, I'm trying to create a login page, and I can't actually enter anything into the TextFiled.

I've tried adding/removing the TextEdditingController and the input decoration. I've tried a TextField and a TextFormField as well

```
Widget loginWidget() {
    return Container(
      width: 650,
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        color: UiColors.CardBlue,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(
                  minWidth: 300,
                  color: UiColors.CardBlue,
                  child: Text("Login", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  onPressed: (){}, // do nothing, this is already the login
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  minWidth: 300,
                  elevation: 10,
                  color: UiColors.ButtonBlue,
                  child: Text("Register", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  onPressed: toggleLogin,
                )
              ],
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: usernameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                labelText: "Email Address",
                hintText: "user@email.com"
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

EDIT: This only seems to effect firefox, works in chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the github repo of flutter_web, it says

"The development workflow is only designed to work with Chrome at the moment."
https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web

At this time, it looks like your prototype development is limited to a chrome browser.

Comment: @Alex I created login screen in flutter web. Design-wise all perfect but textfield I wasn't able to type. When I type in the keyboard it not update in the textfield.

Comment: Same as Magesh I encounter the same problem. Yeh, I work in Google Chrome

Comment: I recommend you all search the issue board on Flutter's github for people experiencing the same situation. I do not work on Flutter's team, nor do I have any context with how your code is consuming a TextField widget. I cannot help any further.

Answer (score 0):

I Know it is late but I will answer this for the use of others. Flutter is currently in process of completing its framework for web. So, the fact that the `TextField` is not working is due to the version of flutter_web. Therefore I recommend you to use older issues from github in your `pubspec.yaml` file like below:

```
name: newweb
description: An app built using Flutter for web

environment:
  # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
  sdk: '>=2.3.0-dev.0.1 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any
  provider: any
  rxdart: ^0.22.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  json_annotation: ^2.4.0
  intl: 0.15.8
  firebase: any


dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.4.0
  build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0
  pedantic: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: ^3.0.0
  test: any

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      ref: cc38319
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui
  provider:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/kevmoo/provider
      ref: flutter_web
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions but couldn't fix it. Whatever I was typing in TextField or TextFormField or [autocomplete_textfield](https://pub.dev/packages/autocomplete_textfield), the characters were not visible.

I fixed it by opening the Widget as a `showGeneralDialog()` instead of using `Navigator.of(...)`. Here is the sample code.

```
await showGeneralDialog(
    barrierColor: AppStyle.primaryColor.withOpacity(0.3),
    transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {
      return Transform.scale(
        scale: a1.value,
        child: Opacity(opacity: a1.value, child: WidgetScreenToOpen()),
      );
    },
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    barrierDismissible: true,
    barrierLabel: 'Label',
    context: context,
    pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {
      return Container();
    }).then((result) {
  return result;
});
```